# HTML Email Disclaimer not working (Office 365/Exchange Online)

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to append a disclaimer to all emails.
That's my HTML Code which is appended by Exchange to all mails:

```
<hr>
<div style="font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;">
    <a href="https://cypexx.com" style="text-decoration:none; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <img src="https://cypexx.com/frontend/src/icons/header/favicon.png" style="width: 2%; height: auto; margin-top: 0.4em; margin-bottom: 0.4em;">
        <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 160%; margin-top: 0.1em; margin-left: 0.2em;">
            <span style="color: transparent; 
            -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.08em;
            -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(177,186,196,1);
            "
            >Cypexx</span> 
            <span style="color: rgba(0,169,170,1);">Hosting</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div style="text-align:center; color: darkred;">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style=" margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: 0.5em;"></i>
        <br>
        <span>If you are not the addressee of this mail, please delete this message immediately. It would be nice if you could also inform the sender about the wrong delivery. 
            <br>
            In case you think this is spam, please contact </span>
        <a href="mailto:support@cypexx.com">support@cypexx.com</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I send an email, the following is shown by Outlook and other Mail clients:

```
________________________________

[https://cypexx.com/frontend/src/icons/header/favicon.png] <https://cypexx.com>
Cypexx Hosting

If you are not the addressee of this mail, please delete this message immediately. It would be nice if you could also inform the sender about the wrong delivery.
In case you think this is spam, please contact support@cypexx.com<mailto:support@cypexx.com>
```

I know that mail clients parse html/css code in a different way browsers do, but I am not sure why my code is not working?

Does someone know what's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. Div will not support some case of webmail and outlook. I have changed to span. Still needed you can proceed with table also.

```html
<span style="font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;">
        <a href="https://cypexx.com" style="text-decoration:none; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
            <img src="https://cypexx.com/frontend/src/icons/header/favicon.png"
                style="width: 2%; height: auto; margin-top: 0.4em; margin-bottom: 0.4em;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 160%; margin-top: 0.1em; margin-left: 0.2em;">
                <span style="color: transparent; 
            -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.08em;
            -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(177,186,196,1);
            ">Cypexx</span>
                <span style="color: rgba(0,169,170,1);">Hosting</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <span style="text-align:center; color: darkred;">
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" style=" margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: 0.5em;"></i>
            <br>
            <span>If you are not the addressee of this mail, please delete this message immediately. It would be nice if
                you could also inform the sender about the wrong delivery.
                <br>
                In case you think this is spam, please contact </span>
            <a href="mailto:support@cypexx.com">support@cypexx.com</a>.
        </span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two HTML elements that support a subset of the cascading style sheets properties are called out: `DIV` and `P`. `DIV` and `P` support a subset of Word–supported cascading style sheet:

- align
- class
- dir
- id
- lang
- nowrap
- style

The following CSS properties are supported:

- text-indent
- margin
- margin-left
- margin-right
- margin-top
- margin-bottom

Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))